# Importing quoted data into SQL, losing data

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have 3 large txt files with tab delimited data that is enclosed in quotes. Here is an example line from one of the files:

```
"deleted for privacy"   185 "12/31/2005"    "01/16/2009"    "deleted for privacy"   false   1   "Accounting Issues" "deleted for privacy"   0   0   0                           1               0               0   "deleted for privacy"
```

I've removed some potentially sensitive information, but you get the idea. It seems to be tab delimited, most values are enclosed in quotes, but not all of them.

The problem is the two date columns are showing up blank for some rows after I import the file into SQL. So, for instance, one of the original files has 5 million rows like the one above with NO blanks in those date columns. Once I bring it into SQL, about a million of those 5 million rows have no value in those date columns. I'm not getting any errors during the import process.

One of the 3 large files is small enough that I'm able to open it in notepad and remove the quotes from all of the values before importing into SQL. This seems to fix the problem. No date values seem to be lost if I remove the quotes before importing into SQL. The problem is 2 of the 3 files are too large to open in notepad to remove the quotes PRIOR to importing.

Comment: which one mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the tool that you're using to do the bulk import, I'll assume bcp or BULK INSERT statement.

I assume that the datatypes of the corresponding columns are of date-time type. In that case SQL server is probably mis-interpreting the date format as dd/mm/yyyy format (European), rather than mm/dd/yyyy (American) style. Values that cannot be converted in the given style are set to NULL.

I usually solve data import issues such as this by importing into a scratch table, where all columns are varchar(max), and then running a post processing stored procedure to transfer imported rows from the scratch table into the final table, defining explicit conversions as required. An alternative to this would be to import using a custom dtsx package, and define the conversions required as a Data Conversion Transformation task.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'm not using a query to import the data, I'm using the import wizard built into SQL-server. I'll try the scratch table idea.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that the scratch table idea worked perfectly. I brought in the data with all of the fields set to varchar(200) and then changed them after they were brought in. Thanks!